# paper-ripple is listening to click events outside of its container

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, paper-elements, polymer-1.0

I'm trying to create a simple ripple effect for a card in my app. It works great, but it is also responding to mouse events outside of its container:

[image]

Code looks like this:

```
<dom-module>
    ...
    <template>
        ...
        <paper-material>
            <div class="wrapper">...</div>
            <paper-ripple></paper-ripple>
        </paper-material>
        ...
    </template>
</dom-module>
```

I don't quite see why it is behaving this way. Any idea?

---

### Added

This whole page is an independant `dom-module`. Apparently using `paper-ripple` in such a fashion causes this to happen. How do I fix this?

Comment: In Polymer 0.5, I had a similar-looking issue, and `position: relative;` on an ancestor element was the solution.

Comment: @TrevorDixon I just tried your suggestion, but unfortunately it didn't fix my problem.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫, there was a recent bug on paper-ripple that was just recently fixed, but not yet packaged in any release. To check and see whether or not this is related to that bug or not, would you mind installing the paper-ripple element from the master branch and giving it a whirl? I've been trying to replicate this scenario in http://plnkr.co/edit/pmjSTkZ6B3m452QGjv3J?p=preview to no avail.

Comment: @VartanSimonian Yep, pulled the latest version and the problem is indeed gone. Now it's working perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it worked for you! I'll go ahead and post an answer for anyone that might be experiencing the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** *(15 June 2015)*: `paper-ripple` 1.0.1 was released on 11 June 2015, which includes [the PR fixing this problem](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-ripple/commit/ea4a535c6c8b8196a1a76223b246ef152893dfd1), making the fixes recommended in this answer ***obsolete.*** Simply update `bower.json` to bind to `PolymerElements/paper-ripple#^1.0.1`.

---

This is a symptom of the very same bug that [plagued another user on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30631617/). The paper-ripple elements are targeting the wrong host element.

A fix [has been merged](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-ripple/commit/ea4a535c6c8b8196a1a76223b246ef152893dfd1) into the official repository, but isn't yet in any release. To use it now, simply use the `master` branch as your version in `bower.json`.

I would recommend keeping tabs on the [releases](https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-ripple/releases) and use an actual version as your dependency instead of the `master` branch as soon as possible.